How do Male Water Opossums' Pouches Function
I stumbled on this question where the answer claims, "The males of both the thylacine and water opposum used/use their pouch to keep their genitalia from getting entangled in vegetation." That sounded ridiculous to me since if the reproductive organs were in a pouch they couldn't do their primary function, so I went looking for sources.
I found a source for the thylacine with some drawing and pictures to help me figure out how this works, so I am all set for that species. Although I found a source saying male water opossums' pouch did have protective functions, but couldn't find a description of how that is suppose to work. Is it similar to the thylacine, or is it different? Thanks for any help you can provide.
